# Issue with coding the communication between a fragment and an async task

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, android-asynctask

I'm new to this concept. I read several threads but I block so thanks in advance for your patience!

In a fragment (frag1) I launch an async task. I want to prevent the user of doing anything while the task is not completed so I want to communicate the % of the task completed so the user waits informed.

I've defined an interface in a java SetVal.java:

```
interface SetVal {
    void setVal(int val);
}
```

My async task:

```
class AsyncCounter extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    private SetVal sender;

    public AsyncCounter(SetVal sv){
        this.sender = sv;
    }

    @Override
    protected  Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for(int i=0;i<60;i++){
            publishProgress(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        Log.i("ASYNC TASK","val: "+values[0]);
        sender.setVal(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    public interface SetVal {
        public void setVal(int val);
    }


    public void setListener(SetVal listener) {
        this.sender = listener;
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to know how to pass the interface to the task.
Is my code correct?
How do I instantiate the async task?

fragment:

```
public class Frag1 extends android.app.Fragment implements SetVal {
    private static TextView txt;
    private int counter;
    SetVal listener;

    public Frag1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        txt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt);
        Button btn = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Frag1", "val: " + counter);
                if (counter > 0) return;
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Frag2 f2 = new Frag2();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f2);
                ft.addToBackStack("f2");
                ft.commit();
            }
        });

        Button btn2 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AsyncCounter ac = new AsyncCounter(???????);
                ac.execute();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void setVal(int val) {
        counter = val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what and why you are trying to do that, but you can pass the Fragment :

Try to create a private method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   startMyAsync();
}

private void startMyAsync() {
    new AsyncCounter(this).execute();
}
```

finally:

```
public AsyncCounter(Frag1 context){
    this.sender = (SetVal)context;
}
```

Comment: MyActivity is not resolved so I tried with Context but it crashed  java.lang.ClassCastException  com.narb.nestedfragments.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.narb.nestedfragments.AsyncCounter$SetVal

Comment: @narb MyActivity is not resolved because i just gave a dummy name. it should be the activity which contains your fragment. Check the updated answer

Comment: that is what I've done (both with Context and Activity) and it's crashing when trying to do "this.sender = (SetVal) context;" with the error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.narb.nestedfragments.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.narb.nestedfragments.AsyncCounter$SetVal